# how can I open Notepad editor by Oracle procedure and show output?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to open Notepad++ after executing a procedure, so the output (a SQL script) appears in Notepad++. How can I do that? Or open Notepad++ only, without showing the output?

I am  using Oracle Apex .

Comment: sorry for that , i am  use oracle apex .

Comment: Do you really want Notepad? Or just a text editor? Have you had a look at the built-in Apex RTF editor? [Find out more](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6401/index-en.html)

Comment: yes, i really notepad++ ,the output it's (sql script ), so i need open it in notepad ++

Comment: Not sure this is possible as stated, since APEX (SQL&PL/SQL bits) does not execute in the browser, but in the database. And there is no way to execute a local command (to start NotePad) from a web page in JS - maybe in Node.js. There are links about integrating APEX and NODE.JS.  And the APEX code (e.g. PL/SQL) while it can write to a file *local to the database* cannot write to the client desktop. This may help: https://community.oracle.com/thread/509622

Comment: @Joe - whilst that thread is pertinent it dates from 2007. Apex has added a lot of capabilities in the intervening years (although I'm not sufficiently familiar with the tool to say whether it can call local applications). Although, generally speaking browser applications do not run external programs on the client machine **by design**. I don't understand why the built-in editor editor (initialised with a fixed font) doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

check for sqldeveloper it has variety of options and simple to use
https://www.oracle.com/in/tools/downloads/sqldev-v192-downloads.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. It can be done using  SQL Plus executable and Windows cmd batch file scripting.

Code outline should be like follows

**inside: batch_file**

```
sqlplus username/pwd@dbname @sql_file.sql

notepad output.txt
```

**inside: sql_file.sql**

```
set serverout on termout on

spool output.txt 

call your procedure with required inputs

spool off

exit;
```

Comment: Why the shouting?